# Spring Boot Batch Processing LocalDatetime Format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss to yyyy-MM-dd

Tags: java, spring-boot, format, localdatetime

I have a problem about formatting localdatetime when I read values from csv file and add them into h2 database.

Here is the example of defining localdatetime in csv file.

```
2000-08-15 19:07:46
```

I want to get 2000-08-15 (removing time part).
Even if I defined `DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");` instead of `DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");` in localDateTimeFormat method , I got an error.

Here is the error shown below.

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '1999-01-25 13:08:57' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2109) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:2008) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:494) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.batchprocessingcsvtodatabase.config.UserProcessor.localDateTimeFormat(UserProcessor.java:37) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.batchprocessingcsvtodatabase.config.UserProcessor.process(UserProcessor.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.batchprocessingcsvtodatabase.config.UserProcessor.process(UserProcessor.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
```

How can I fix it?

Here is the user class shown below.

```
public class User extends BaseEntity{

    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.UUIDCharType")
    private UUID personId;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Gender gender;

    private String country;

    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDateTime birthday;

    private int age;
}
```

Here is the processor class shown below.

```
public class UserProcessor implements ItemProcessor<UserInput, User> {


    @Override
    public User process(UserInput userInput) throws Exception {

        User user = User.builder()
                .personId(UUID.fromString(userInput.getPersonId()))
                .firstName(userInput.getFirstName())
                .lastName(userInput.getLastName())
                .email(userInput.getEmail())
                .country(userInput.getCountry())
                .birthday(localDateTimeFormat(userInput.getBirthday()))
                .gender(userInput.getGender().equals("Male") ? Gender.MALE : Gender.FEMALE)
                .age(Period.between(localDateTimeFormat(userInput.getBirthday()).toLocalDate(), LocalDate.now()).getYears())
                .build();

        return user;
    }

    private LocalDateTime localDateTimeFormat(String birthday) {

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        LocalDateTime formatDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(birthday, formatter);

        return formatDateTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: *I got an error.* please share atleast the message

Comment: I can not repoduce it. Are there any nonprintable character after the date?

Comment: @Jens No. How can I do that?

Comment: This is not related to Spring Batch per se. Please extract the part that is related to date parsing in a unit test or in a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue to be able to help you in an efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the wrong type for `birthday`; it should be `LocalDate` as you want to keep only the date part.

Change

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDateTime birthday;
```

to

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate birthday;
```

You will also need to change the function definition to return `LocalDate` out of the parsed `LocalDateTime` as shown in the demo below:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getLocalDate("2000-08-15 19:07:46"));
    }

    private static LocalDate getLocalDate(String birthday) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        return LocalDateTime.parse(birthday, formatter).toLocalDate();
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2000-08-15
```